# how to convert GMT offset value to +/- HH:MM

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, string-formatting

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");

    int offset1 = timeZone.getRawOffset();
    System.out.println("offset = "+ offset);

    int offsetHrs = offset / 1000 / 60 / 60;
    int offsetMins = offset / 1000 / 60 % 60;

    System.out.println("offsetHrs="+ offsetHrs);
    System.out.println("offsetMins="+ offsetMins);


    GMTOffset = offsetHrs + ":" + offsetMins;
    System.out.println("GMTOffset = " + utzOffset);
```

The out put will be

> offset = 19800000
>
> offsetHrs=5
>
> offsetMins=30
>
> GMT offset = 5:30

i am using this offset value in ms sql server to convert the time zone.
sql server will takes the below format

```
(+/-)HH:MM
```

my result is 5:30 but it's giving an invalid timezone error 
it should be +5:30 .

in another case

> TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT");
>
> in this case offset will be "0"
>
> but ms sql takes only +00:00 or -00:00 (+/- sign must)

can any one help me how to format the offset in  **(+/-)HH:MM**  format.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use

```
int offset = timeZone.getRawOffset();
String gmtTZ = String.format("%s%02d:%02d", 
               offset < 0 ? "-" : "+", 
               Math.abs(offset) / 3600000,
               Math.abs(offset) / 60000 % 60);
```

Comment: Don't we also need to consider DST here? Am I missing anything?